# Sum object values matching specific address

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

How can I search through the objects to total up all of the results for a specific address?

```
   $.ajax({
        url: "https://snowgem.voidr.net/api/payments",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {

            var addr = 's1QR1uT4GvVWgct1sRU226rXiTzCPwf72J3';
            // find object
            var payments = data.find(function (obj) {
                return obj.payments.amounts == addr;
            });  


            console.log(payments);

        },
        error: function() {
          //alert("Was unable to get info!");
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is the response you get from this AJAX call?

Comment: I get undefined

Comment: Then obviously you can't if you don't receive any data.

Comment: Post the response from AJAX, omitting any sensitive properties if any.

Comment: "I get undefined", why are you asking to sort the response if you don't have a working AJAX call to start with?

Comment: Because I'm unsure where to proceed from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can use js to get total from `amounts` for given `addr` address -

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "https://snowgem.voidr.net/api/payments",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {

    var addr = 's1QR1uT4GvVWgct1sRU226rXiTzCPwf72J3';
    // find object
    var totalAmount = 
        data[0].payments.
            map(payment => payment.amounts).  //get all amount object
            map(amounts => amounts[addr]).    //get amount from addr
            filter(price => price).           //filter undefined amount
            reduce((first, second) => {       //sum amount
                return first + second;
            });

    console.log(totalAmount);

  },
  error: function() {
    //alert("Was unable to get info!");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hit `Run code snippet`  to verify output. :)